# Progressive web app and AngularDart

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I am currently looking for a web framework for my next project and for some reasons I'm interested in angular**dart**.

But at the same time I want my webapp to follow PWA guidelines.

I searched quite a lot, but I haven't found an example of PWA in angulardart.
I saw some examples for the JS counterpart or found [`pwa`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pwa) dart package, but I lack the knowledge of angulardart framework to know if it's possible in dart.

So, is it possible to make a PWA in angulardart ?

Comment: Angular doesn't provide concrete support but you can use the pwa package with Angular.

Comment: But how do you download only the required code then ?

Comment: You can use Darts deferred loading feature. Angular supports that as well. This causes the code to be split and only loaded what's actually used. This is independent of the pwa package. pwa is more about resources like images, css, ...

Comment: @RémiRousselet, Günter Zöchbauer : can I ask you please ? We are now in the end of 2020 , do you think that AngularDart is good framework to build a website ? I have worked a bit with Flutter but it's difficult for me because I am used to work with html, css , js ... I see Angular (typeScript) is more popular than AngularDart , but what is your opinion ? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deferred loading in plain Dart

- https://news.dartlang.org/2014/08/dart-16-adds-support-for-deferred.html

Angular supports deferred loading for statically and dynamically added components.

- https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/f7bb02861ad4aa8b6cc60df784091480bb07e6eb/angular_ast/CHANGELOG.md#040-alpha2
- https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/master/doc/component_loading.md#deferred-loading

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/9a2b824cef4e1c45871bb7fad7cbbb1af1b80ed1/ROADMAP.md#code-size

> AngularDart is suitable as a framework for a [progressive web app](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/).

More specific documentation seems sparse though.

For pwa features beyond deferred loading use the pwa package you mention in your question.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know dart supported deferred loading. Thanks