# Quality and complete PWA (Progressive Web Apps) with dart or/and AngularDart

Tags: dart, progressive-web-apps, angular-dart, dart-html

Can I build a complete and quality PWA (Progressive Web Apps) using just dart language - or AngularDart - with no javascript prior experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can build a PWA using AngularDart.
AngularDart is usually used for native apps and can be compiled into javascript. With tree shaking, type inference and minification, [Dart](https://developers.google.com/web/shows/cds/2013/dart-for-the-modern-web-developer) can help you optimize your web app. Therefore it is suitable as a framework for Progressive Web App.

Here is another [SO related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798934/progressive-web-app-and-angulardart) regarding PWA using AngularDart.

Answer (score 1):

We need to get some documentation out for this, but we do have an example application:

Example: https://hnpwa.dartlang.org/

Source: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/tree/master/examples/hacker_news_pwa

Comment: I am assuming from your answer that I can build anything that js developer can build in pwa without getting to learn js ... I am also assuming that pwa and service_worker libs in dart are mature enough for any pwa production ... right ?

Comment: pwa and service_worker packages need some work. If you follow along with what this app does, you should be okay, though.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.